# WPF DataGrid Mysterious Margin

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, margin

I'm using MahApps in my project for his cool VS2012 style and trying to implement DataGrid to style it.
I'm almost finished and detected a mysterious margin around the DataGrid (the same as around a ListView though).
If you look carefully, you'd be able to see it on the screen.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lpuf.jpg]

I tried to look with Snoop but he makes my app crash as soon as I try to inject the "sniffer".
I was able to do it with another WPF Inspector and I didn't saw any margin in the DataGrid template.

Does anybody have an idea of this margin's origin ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I set Margin to -1 it solves the problem. Is this really a solution ? :3

Comment: Today I had a similar problem templating a `DataGrid`, it was driving me crazy that even though I defined the heights and widths explicitly, it was just ending up going +-3. I tried to find what causing it for hours with no luck. In the end I put negative margins and just decided to let it go.

Comment: I think i'ts the only simple way to solve the problem :).